# JQueryUI SwitchClass has no effect on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**Problem:**

I am switching an element's display between 2 classes ("*class1*" & "*class2*", say) using the JQueryUI `SwitchClass()` method. This is supposed to change the display back and forth, but I cannot switch back to the original class.

The `$('.class1').click()` function works fine, and switches the `<a>` element's class to "*class2*", styles and all.
The `$('.class2').click()` function does not fire after this on clicking the same `<a>` element, although the CSS class has already been switched successfully. I'd like to switch the class back to "*class1*" on click.

**Sample Code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/buddhaspake/F6BE8/1/

I am pretty sure I am missing something simple... Any solution/workaround will be much appreciated!!

**EDIT:**

I found 2 solutions to my problem (Described below)
**1. SOLUTION to** `SwitchClass()` **issue:** 
(As suggested by Rajaprabhu): to use jQuery Event-delegation model to add a istener to an outer element (the *nearest* static parent).
Sample code here: http://jsfiddle.net/buddhaspake/F6BE8/5

**2. WORKAROUND using** `toggleClass()`**:** 
(As suggested by adeneo): to use jQuery toggleClass() method as per sample code in the link in adeneo's comment.

Comment: The question is why are you using switchClass, jQuery UI also has [toggleClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) with just about the same arguments, so you could just do something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/F6BE8/3/**

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, I was having a similar problem with toggleClass() due to my incorrect usage of the method. Your example will probably be more useful for my purpose than event-delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`event-delegation`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) since you are changing the class at run time,

```
$(document).on('click', '.class2', function() {

});
```

Side Note : I just delegated the event to the document, since I don't know about the static parent in your context, use a closest static parent to delegate the event. because if we rely upon the document then obviously it will be the last element while the event got bubbled up to the DOM tree.

Comment: Please explain pros / cons about binding on parent node. Especially binding on `document`

Comment: Thanks both for the useful pointers,  I tried modifying the example and it worked: 

http://jsfiddle.net/buddhaspake/F6BE8/5/